# Allowing anyone on the web to join a Google Group

Tags: google-groups

I have a Google Group set up as part of the Google Suite (basic account). When creating the Google Group, I set the "Join the Group" permission to "Anyone on the web".

How do people now join the group?

---

I tried pasting the standard join link in an incognito tab:

https://groups.google.com/a/example.com/forum/#!forum/examplelist/join

but it shows an error message such as:

> **Authorization Failed**
>
> This group is on a private domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you must follow [these instructions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/132456/207) fully to both:

1. Allow outside domain access.
2. Allow anyone on the web to see the group in the directory.

If you omit #1, you'll see the "Authorization failed" error.

If you omit #2, you'll see an error:

> You do not have permission to access this content. (#418)

Therefore, in order for people to join, the group must be publicly discoverable via the directory too.